# How to create a board game in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Batlle-ship program project to do. I'm trying to figure out how to print a board game (NxN).

I was using a for-loop nested like this one:

```
for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){ 
    for(int=j=0; j<=10; j++){
        System.out.println("-");
    }
    System.out.println("A B C D E F G H I J");
}
```

To print something like this:

```
  A B C D E F G H I J
A - - - - - - - - - -
B - - - - - - - - - -
C - - - - - - - - - -
D - - - - - - - - - -
E - - - - - - - - - -
F - - - - - - - - - -
G - - - - - - - - - -
H - - - - - - - - - -
I - - - - - - - - - -
J - - - - - - - - - -
```

But there is something wrong because it doesn't show the board like that. I'll appreciate if someone can help identify what happens here.

Comment: try printing " -" in the for loop instead of just "-". The extra space will make what's printed out look like a grid.

Comment: You should really tell us what output your getting or else we cant really help you. One problem may be that `System.out.println()` appends a newline each time it is called. Try using `System.out.printf()` instead because it wont  add a newline after each `-` and then you can add newlines where you see fit

Comment: `println()` means print text AND newline character (and puts carret on next line). Thats why your code prints one symbol per line. If you want the carret to stay on the same line, use `System.out.print("....")` instead.

Comment: `public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Tester game = new Tester();
    }

    public Tester(){
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.printf("A B C D E F G H I J");


            for(int j=0; j<=10; j++){
                System.out.println("- ");
            }

        }
    }
}`
I made some modifications but now it just prints 10 boards instead of one. This is the output (10 times it prints):
A B C D E F G H I J- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Test if you're on the first row OR the first column based on your indexs values.

B) If you are, print the letters. I'd suggest you put them in an array and acces them by their index which would correspond to the index of... the row/column in question.

C) If it is not the case, print "-"

D) Do not forget to print the spaces each time you pass the inner loop

---

**SPOILER**

Here are two ways to achieve what you want

```
String[] letters = {" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= 10 ; j++){
        System.out.print(i == 0 || j == 0 ? i == 0 ? letters[j] : letters[i] : "-");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

```
String[] letters = {" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"}; 
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= 10 ; j++){
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.print(letters[j]);
        } else if (j == 0){
            System.out.print(letters[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.print("-");
        }           
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it's printing better now.

Comment: Do you know a way that I can make the board size (NxN) from the keyboard input? Restricting the min number of rows/columns being 5, the max being 26 @YassinHajaj

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will work for you:

```
    System.out.println("  A B C D E F G H I J");
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){ 
        System.out.print((char)('A'+i)+" ");
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            System.out.print("- ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but here's a simple code to print the board using two dimensional array:

```
int row,col;
char[][] boardGame = new char[11][11];
for(row=0; row<boardGame.length;row++){
for(col=0; col<boardGame[row].length;col++){
if(row==0)
boardGame[row][col]=(char)('A'+col);
else if(col==0)
boardGame[row][col]=(char)('A'+row);
else boardGame[row][col]='-';
}}

for(row=0; row<boardGame.length;row++){
System.out.println();
for(col=0; col<boardGame[row].length;col++){
System.out.print(boardGame[row][col]);
}}
```